# Find Tag with field_in_set over 3 Tables without Join

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables :

> 1. link_art_a
> 2. link_art_b
> 3. link_art_c

I want to now search for "**car**" and this output on one side .

The tables are almost identical , fields that I need :

**`id, name , mod_name , picture , hits.`**

The field is where there wanted , is separated by a comma , for example :

```
Car , truck , SUV , bike
```

> Field: "tag"

I've **FIND_IN_SET** attempts , but I always get all the entries in the database and not with the "**car**" .

What I have tried so far :

```
SELECT id, name, mod_name, picture, hits from link_art_a 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, name, mod_name, picture, hits from link_art_b 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, name, mod_name, picture, hits from link_art_c 
    where   
    find_in_field('Car', tag) > 0 order by name asc
```

Does anyone have an idea how I get my desired result ?

Edit:
Hello,

The problem is that I get all records including those that do not contain the desired word such as "car" .

The MySQL Dump:

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

CREATE TABLE `link_art_a` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `mod_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `picture` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `hits` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `tag` varchar(250) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `link_art_a` (`id`, `name`, `mod_name`, `picture`, `hits`, `tag`) VALUES
(1, 'A8', 'a8.html', 'default.jpg', 251, 'car,sports car,sport,fast'),
(2, 'VW Beetle', 'vw-beetle', 'default.jpg', 269, 'car,fun,slow');

CREATE TABLE `link_art_b` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `mod_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `picture` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `hits` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `tag` varchar(250) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `link_art_b` (`id`, `name`, `mod_name`, `picture`, `hits`, `tag`) VALUES
(1, 'Surfboard', 'surfboard', 'default.jpg', 142, 'fun,sport,water'),
(2, 'Sport boat', 'sport-boat', 'default.jog', 163, 'sport,fun,water,fast');

CREATE TABLE `link_art_c` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `mod_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `picture` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `hits` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `tag` varchar(250) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `link_art_c` (`id`, `name`, `mod_name`, `picture`, `hits`, `tag`) VALUES
(1, 'Houseboat', 'houseboat', 'default.jog', 144, 'house,boat,water'),
(2, 'Speedboat', 'speedboat', 'default.jpg', 142, 'water,boot,speed,fast');


ALTER TABLE `link_art_a` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`), ADD KEY `tag` (`tag`);
ALTER TABLE `link_art_b` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),  ADD KEY `tag` (`tag`);
ALTER TABLE `link_art_c` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),  ADD KEY `tag` (`tag`);


ALTER TABLE `link_art_a`
  MODIFY `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=3;
ALTER TABLE `link_art_b`
  MODIFY `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=3;
ALTER TABLE `link_art_c`
  MODIFY `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=3;COMMIT;
```

Comment: can you please add sample data of all 3 tables at least 2 two different records in each table.

Comment: So what's the problem you are facing with your current query? better post your current result and expected result based on some sample data. @frank

Comment: @Noman MySQL Dump added
The result is faulty , a search for "fast" delivery also " VW Beetle " , but this does not have " almost " in "tag"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `where` clause applies to the last `select` only.

You have to add `where` to all `select` statements

Like this:

```
SELECT id, name, mod_name, picture, hits from link_art_a
where   
find_in_set('Car', tag) > 0 

UNION ALL
SELECT id, name, mod_name, picture, hits from link_art_b 
where   
find_in_set('Car', tag) > 0 

UNION ALL
SELECT id, name, mod_name, picture, hits from link_art_c 
where   
find_in_set('Car', tag) > 0
```

**NOTES:**

1. you must remove `order by` in this case.
2. it is `find_in_set()` not `find_in_field()`

Or add it to all of them

```
SELECT id, name, mod_name, picture, hits from
(
 SELECT id, name, mod_name, picture, hits, tag from link_art_a 
 UNION ALL
 SELECT id, name, mod_name, picture, hits, tag from link_art_b 
 UNION ALL
 SELECT id, name, mod_name, picture, hits, tag from link_art_c 
) as t1
where   
find_in_set('Car', t1.tag) > 0 order by t1.name asc
```

Comment: MySQL Error: #1305 - FUNCTION qb.find_in_field does not exist.

Find_in_set provides only 2 results , although more than 2 records with " fun" are present . Idea?

Comment: Just for Info: MySql Server-Version: 5.5.49-0+deb8u1 - (Debian)

Comment: @frank I tested it on `fun` and it returned 3 results.

Comment: my pleasure @frank